# Extra space after equation with footnote

Tags: equations, footnotes

So I need a footnote after an equation and I found this solution:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{fn}{(}{)\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
    \section{Example 1}
    \usetagform{fn} 
    \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
    \end{equation}\footnotetext{Footnote}
    \usetagform{default}
    \section{Example 2}
\end{document}
```

However this adds extra spacing after the equation as shown in the picture below. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: As a matter of principle, footnotes should be used for material of minor importance and/or auxiliary nature. If you need to provide explanations to the equations, these explanations in all likelihood be placed in the body of the text, *not* inside footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `\footnotetext` in a safer place, and avoid white space around the `\usetagform`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{fn}{(}{)\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
    \section{Example 1}
    \usetagform{fn} 
    \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\footnotetext{Footnote}
    \end{equation}%
   \usetagform{default}%
    \section{Example 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do the two percentage signs change?

Comment: This solution does remove the whitspace though the number of the footnote in the footer is zero and in the text one.

Comment: @djedefre that would be wrong then:-) I'll fix, look again in a bit

Comment: @djedefre fixed, note that the dance with adding and subtracting 1 to the footnote counter is only needed as you have no actual text in this document, just equations and section headings so the only "safe" place to use `\footnotetext` is in the equation, but then it is before the equation number so gets the wrong footnote number without some help.

Comment: @djedefre on `%` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines